# Why don't all keys work on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

For a while now some keys on my laptop don't work. It is usually <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>t</kbd> that don't work sometimes, but other times they do. I could be typing anything and then the next thing I know I've written "*youue*" instead of *YouTube*. 
Here is he model: https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GP72-2QE-Leopard-Pro.html#hero-overview

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: we need details. model, operating system. and can you remember a pattern when the keys work and when they don't? Only in certain applications or everyhere?

Comment: If you plug in an external keyboard, does it have the same behavior?